# Moodle: How to set default blocks and their order in a new course?

Tags: moodle

I want to change default blocks and also order of them when a new course is created. I guess this should be done through editing source code, but if  there is a way in application layer, that would be great!

I don't want to send my task to others. Finding out:

- What is the proper way;
- Which files should be checked;
- What is the systematic way of doing it: through code, database or application.

is ok!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add following config variables in your `config.php` file according to your course  format setting. In this setting colon is provided to separate  the left and right blocks.

```
$CFG->defaultblocks_site = 'site_main_menu,course_list:course_summary,calendar_month';

$CFG->defaultblocks_social = 'participants,search_forums,calendar_month,calendar_upcoming,social_activities,recent_activity,course_list';

$CFG->defaultblocks_topics = 'participants,activity_modules,search_forums,course_list:news_items,calendar_upcoming,recent_activity';

$CFG->defaultblocks_weeks = 'participants,activity_modules,search_forums,course_list:news_items,calendar_upcoming,recent_activity';
```

Comment: I have not tested your answer yet. Can you decorate (format) your answer codes please?

Comment: Currently doing from mobile so decorating options are not comming

Comment: Thanks, I got what is $CFG->defaultblocks_site, what about tree other variables? which of them is related to newly created course?